# Multiple (but not all) card slots

Tags: javascript

Trying to recreate a game in which cards are sorted into card slots. I can make it so that card 'a' goes into the first card slot 'Even', but I want to make it so that card 'a' can also go in the the second card slot 'Even.' Similarly, I want card 'b' to be able to go into either 'Even' slot. Ditto cards 'c' and 'd' for either 'Odd' slot and 'e' and 'f' for the either 'Even and Odd' slots. Any ideas?

```
// Create the pile of shuffled cards
    var equations = [];
    equations [ 0 ] = {x:1, y:'a'};
    equations [ 1 ] = {x:2, y:'b'};
    equations [ 2 ] = {x:3, y:'c'};
    equations [ 3 ] = {x:4, y:'d'};
    equations [ 4 ] = {x:5, y:'e'};
    equations [ 5 ] = {x:6, y:'f'};

  equations.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .4 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + equations[i].y + '</div>').data( 'number', equations[i].x ).attr( 'id', 'card'+equations[i].x ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the card slots
  var words = [ 'Even', 'Even', 'Odd)', 'Odd', 'Even + Odd', 'Even + Odd' ];
  for ( var i=1; i<=6; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
  // change the card colour, position it directly
  // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
  // again

  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  }  

  // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
  // and reset the cards for another go

  if ( correctCards == 6) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '430px',
      top: '150px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '180px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have a one-to-one relationship between cards and slots, but it sounds like you want a one-to-many relationship.

So first thing you need to do is define the correct answer for each of your equations by adding a third value.

```
equations [ 0 ] = {x:1, y:'a', correct: 'Even'};
```

(You can make this an array if you want multiple correct answers.)

Next, you need to add this answer to the card's data.

```
.data( 'correct', equations[i].correct )
```

And finally check for the answer when you handle the drop

```
var slotAnswer = $(this).text();
var cardAnswer = ui.draggable.data( 'correct' );
if ( slotAnswer == cardAnswer) {
```

It might be better to store the slot answer in the data instead of just the text.

Also, you have a typo in the slot name of `Odd)`